# How to get id from url in rest project

Tags: node.js, rest

I am writing rest project. I want to create delete function. This is my core.js:

```
    $scope.deleteWriter = function (id) {
    $http.delete('/writer/id')
        .success(function (data) {
        $scope.todos = data;
        console.log(data);
    })
        .error(function (data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
};
```

This is my server.js

```
app.delete('/writer/:id', function (req, res) {
var reqBody = '';
var id = req.params.id;
req.on("data", function (data) {
    reqBody += data;
    if (reqBody.length > 1e7)//10MB
        httpMsgs.show404(req, res);
});
req.on("end", function () {

    wr.delete(req, res, id);
});
})
```

All I want is to get my id from url and send to the function that will remove it from database. But this code doesn't work. It just puts string "id" to the my id value. What should I sent to wr.delete?

Comment: you should read `id` value from the delete call params

Comment: how could I do this?

Comment: I don't recall the exact way to do that, should be something like `var id = req.params.id` or something like this. Try googlin 'node get routing parameter'

Comment: I have just edited my code. This doesn't help me because it just put string "id" to my id value. What is the reason?

Comment: The reason is thst you are actually passig the string 'id' to the node application. Use `$http.delete('/writer/'+id)` instead of your actual code in your first code Block

Comment: Oh, silly mistake! Thanks. it works!